# SAPUI5 - SmartForm/ SmartField - disable automatic odata backend update

Tags: forms, odata, sapui5

I started to use SmartForm and SmartField in my SAPUI5 application. When I'm in the edit mode, the changes will be directly updated in the backend. This is not what I want.

What I want is to trigger the odata submitChanges function manually, when the user has finished all changes and press a save button. When the cancel button is pressed I want to reset the changes in the odata model using resetChanges.

So the question is - Is it possible to disable the automatic update of SmartField - or - what is the best practice to use SmartFrom with this functionality?

Example:

xml view:

```
<smartForm:SmartForm 
  id="smartForm"
  title="General"
  editTogglable="true">
  <smartForm:Group label="Product">
    <smartForm:GroupElement>
        <smartField:SmartField value="{Id}" />
    </smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartForm:GroupElement>                    
        <smartField:SmartField value="{Name}" />
    </smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartForm:GroupElement>                    
        <smartField:SmartField value="{Description}" />
    </smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartForm:GroupElement>                    
        <smartField:SmartField value="{Valid}" />
    </smartForm:GroupElement>
  </smartForm:Group>
</smartForm:SmartForm>
```

manifest:

```
"": {
  "dataSource": "mainService",
  "preload": true,
  "settings" : {
    "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"                  
  }         
}
```

Cheers J.

Comment: What do you mean under "the changes will be directly updated in the backend"? Smart controls are just wrappers on the original onces (based on metadata/annotations). Are you sure that in your case one single edit, let's say of a particular input in the form, leads to immediate PUT request? I don't think so. Can you then show an example?

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych
I'm changing the name or description. Then, after the field loses the focus, the PUT request will be sent

Comment: Which ui5 version and odatamodel do you use?

Comment: Im using ui5 version 1.46 and odata version 2.0. I'm using the worklist template.

Comment: How do you bind this smartform and why don't you set the "entityType" property there? Also you can play around "refreshAfterChange" and "defaultBindingMode" in manifest.